# How to change a variable in a class from outside the class to encrypt data?

Tags: php

I'm new to the whole OOP and encrypting with openssl_encrypt. So I thought I would try a few things out first.
I found the following code online to encrypt some data.

I want to change the variable `private $_secret_key`outside of the class, to bind it to a specific password or something similar, so only one person or a handful of People have control of the decrypted data.

My Problem is, if I change the `$keyvalue` the encrypted text does not change. If I change the `private $_secret_key` inside the class to a word or phrase, the encrypted text in the output is changed.
I just can't wrap my head around the fact, that the `$encrypt->setSecretkey($keyvalue);` seems to have no impact to the whole encrypting process.

I hope I could I explain my problem well enough, as english is not my first language.

Thanks for input, tips and suggestions

```
class Encryption
{
  const AES_256_CBC = 'aes-256-cbc';
    
  private $_secret_key = ''; // variable here
  private $_secret_iv  = ''; // other variable here
  private $_encryption_key;
  private $_iv;
    


  function setSecretkey($_secret_key) {
      $this->_secret_key = $_secret_key;
  }

  function getSecretkey() {
      echo 'new key =  ' . $this->_secret_key . '<br>';
  }
    


  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_encryption_key = hash('sha256', $this->_secret_key);
    $this->_iv             = substr(hash('sha256', $this->_secret_iv), 0, 16);
  }


  public function encryptString($data)
  {
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, self::AES_256_CBC, $this->_encryption_key, 0, $this->_iv));
  }

  public function decryptString($data)
  {
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), self::AES_256_CBC, $this->_encryption_key, 0, $this->_iv);
  }

  public function setEncryptionKey($key)
  {
    $this->_encryption_key = $key;
  }

  public function setInitVector($iv)
  {
    $this->_iv = $iv;
  }
    

   

}

$keyvalue = 'test';

$raw_string = 'Testtext';

$encrypt = new Encryption();
$encrypt->setSecretkey($keyvalue);
$encrypt->getSecretkey();

$encrypted = $encrypt->encryptString($raw_string);


echo 'encrypted text = ' . $encrypted;
```

The Output is like this:

```
new key = test

encrypted text = NDNSMThoZGhzck52RmcwOXJ6cURNQT09
```

If I change `$keyvalue` to something else, the encrypted text stays the same. If I change the `private $_secret_key` to `'exampletext'` the output is:

`encrypted text = N1lSZUMzQ1o3Uks1amI5M0lZSnZ6dz09`

I tried a lot of different code snippets for changing variables inside of classes. The output seems to be always the same. The `$encrypt->getSecretkey();` gives me the `$keyvalue`, but the encrypted text stays the same, no matter what I do.

Comment: The encryption uses `$this->_encryption_key`, which is only set in `__construct`. Setting `$this->_secret_key` afterwards doesn't change `$this->_encryption_key` anymore.

Comment: Either regenerate `_encryption_key` whenever `_secret_key` changes, or (better) just delay the generation of `_encryption_key` until just before using it. Or maybe take `_secret_key` as a required constructor argument. (Same for `_iv`.)